# Plugin para postar conteúdo no Facebook assim que publicado no site

Tags: facebook

Coloquei um plugin do `wp` para compartilhar meu conteúdo assim que publicado no `facebook`. O `plugin` pediu a `api key` e `secret` eu utilizei a que tenho do `instant article` mas diz que não tem permissão.

Meu `instant article`, também não esta funcionando eu não entendo porque. Será que é porque tenho `hotwords` nas minhas páginas? `NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster` alguém pode indicar um plugin de mais simples utilização para o mesmo objetivo ?

Comment: Você chegou a criar o aplicativo no Facebook e gerar os Tokens ?

Comment: sim mas é o mesmo do instant article - Gumball